# Does the derivative with respect to a matrix have a Kronecker product matrix representation?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, matrix-calculus, tensors

I'm confused why I end up with two matrices that are transposes of each other when I take a tensor inner product of a third order tensor with a vector, when I use two different Kronecker product matrix tensor representations that I believe are equal.

Let $A$ be a matrix and $x$ and $y$ be vectors.  Using index notation,
$$ y_i = A_{ip}x_p $$
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial{y_i}}{\partial{A_{jk}}} 
&=
\frac{\partial{(A_{jk}}x_p)}{\partial{A_{jk}}}
\\ &=
\delta_{ij}\delta_{pk}x_p
\\ &= 
\delta_{ij}x_p 
\end{aligned}
$$
So, the derivative is a third order tensor, and with $\otimes$ the tensor product
$$
\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{A}} = I \otimes x
$$
But since
$$
\delta_{ij}x_p = x_p\delta_{ij}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{A}} = x \otimes I
$$
But the tensor product is not commutative.  Also, the Kronecker product representations are different.  For example, assume $x$ is $2 \times1$ and $I$ is $2 \times 2$.
$$
x_p\delta_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_1 \\ x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} 
=
A_{pij}
$$
$$
\delta_{ij}x_p = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_1 \\ 0 & x_2 \end{bmatrix} 
=
B_{ijp}
$$

If I now take a tensor inner product of $A$ or $B$ with $z$ a $2 \times 1$ matrix.
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x \otimes I) \cdotp z &= A_{pij}z_k\delta_{jk} 
\\&= A_{pij}z_j 
\\&= C_{pi}
\\&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{111}z_1 + A_{112}z_2 & A_{121}z_1 + A_{122}z_2 \\
A_{211}z_1 + A_{212}z_2 & A_{221}z_1 + A_{222}z_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1z_1 & x_1z_2 \\
x_2z_1 & x_2z_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=
xz^T
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
(I \otimes x) \cdotp z &= z_kB_{ijp}\delta_{ik} 
\\&= z_iB_{ijp}
\\&= D_{jp}
\\&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1B_{111} + z_2B_{211} & z_1B_{112} + z_2B_{212} \\
z_1B_{121} + z_2B_{221} & z_1B_{122} + z_2B_{222} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1x_1 & z_1x_2 \\
z_2x_1 & z_2x_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\\&=
zx^T
\end{aligned}
$$

Does it even make sense to represent a third order tensor with a Kronecker product, and what am I missing?

Comment: $\delta_{ij}x_p \neq x_p \delta_{ij}$

Comment: $\delta_{ij}x_p = x_p\delta_{ij}$ but $\delta_{ij}x_pz_p \ne x_p\delta_{ij}z_j$

Comment: Tensor products do not commute please get yourself a good reference. Tensor $T_{ijp}=\delta_{ij}x_p$ has element $T_{112}=x_2$; tensor $Q_{pij}=x_p\delta_{ij}$ has element $Q_{112}=0$. So $T \neq Q$; by the way using the flat index notation where all indices are downstairs does not help.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\ell}
\def\bb{\mathbb}
\def\kp{\otimes}  \def\hp{\odot}  \def\dp{\star}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\E{{\cal E}} \def\F{{\cal F}}
\def\G{{\cal G}} \def\M{{\cal M}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}  \def\mt{\mapsto}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\wrt#1{\LR{{\rm wrt}\;#1}}
$The dyadic product $(\dp)$ of $n$ vectors
creates an $n^{th}$ order **tensor**, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\M = e\dp f\dp g\dp h
 \qiq \M_{ijk\l} = e_i\, f_j\, g_k\, h_\l 
}$$
whereas their Kronecker product $(\kp)$ merely creates a very long **vector**.

Similarly, the Kronecker product of $n$ matrices creates a very big **matrix**.

In short, you cannot construct higher-order tensors using only Kronecker products.

On the other hand, you can use Kronecker products to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) an equation
$$\eqalign{
 a = \vecc{A},\;y \equiv \vecc{y} \qiq y=\vecc{Ax} = \CLR{x^T\kp I}a  \\
}$$
The gradient of this equation $\wrt a$ is obviously the matrix in $\c{\rm red.}$

One more product (indispensable for doing *Matrix Calculus*) is the double-dot product $(:)$
$$ F = \M:A \qiq F_{ij} = \sum_k\sum_\l\M_{ijk\l}\,A_{k\l} $$
When applied to matrices, this simplifies to the trace function
$$\eqalign{
M:A  = \sum_k\sum_\l M_{k\l}\,A_{k\l} \;=\; \trace{M^TA} \\
}$$

---

Using the ideas above, the gradient of the original equation $\wrt A$ is easy to calculate
$$\eqalign{
y &= Ax \;=\; \LR{I\dp x}:A \\
dy &= \CLR{I\dp x}:dA &\{ {\sf differential} \} \\
\grad yA &= \LR{I\dp x} \qiq&\grad{y_i}{A_{jk}} = \delta_{ij}\,x_k \\
}$$
which is obviously a $3^{rd}$ order tensor.

### Update

Note that $\LR{x^T\kp I}\ne\LR{I\dp x}$ since the LHS is a matrix (a second-order tensor) while the RHS is a third-order tensor. These objects are not dimensionally compatible.

However, there is a one-to-one mapping of every component on the RHS to every component on the LHS, e.g.
$$\LR{x^T\kp I}_{(\o,\o)}=\LR{I\dp x}_{(\o,\o,\o)}$$
Similarly, $\vecc A\ne A$ although a one-to-one mapping also exists in this situation.

Another example that often trips people up is
$\:\vecc A\ne\vecc{A^T}\ne\vecc{A}^T$

Comment: thanks this is useful.   So $\delta_{ij}x_k = I \star x = x^T \otimes I$ Does this mean that $x_k\delta_{ij} = x^T \star I = I \otimes x$

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to use index notation:
$$
y_i = {A^p}_i x_p
$$
So, for example,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
{A^1}_1 & {A^2}_1 \\
{A^1}_2  & {A^2}_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now we write the differential,
$$
dy_i = d{A^p}_i x_p = \delta^p_{p'}\delta^{i'}_i x_p d{A^{p'}}_{i'} = \delta^{i'}_i x_{p'} d{A^{p'}}_{i'}
$$
and, as expected, $\partial y /\partial A$ is a third order tensor $\delta^{i'}_i x_{p'}$.

What is the structure of this tensor? Using the set up
in the example,
$$
{\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial A}\right)^{i'}}_{ip'}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & 0 \\
x_2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & x_1 \\
0 & x_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So for $i=1$ we have a matrix whose first column is $\pmb{x}$ and the second column is zero.
For $i=2$ we have the reverse.

Is there a way to convert this to a Kronecker product? First $\pmb{x}\otimes\pmb{I}$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
x_2 \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_1
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
 \begin{bmatrix}
x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which does not work.
Next $\pmb{I} \otimes \pmb{x}$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
&
0\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix} 
\\
\\
0 \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
&
1\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & 0 \\
x_2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &x_1  \\
0 & x_2  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which works.

Since $\delta^{i'}_i x_{p'}$ is a third order tensor, its inner product with a vector $z_{i'}$ is,
$$
\delta^{i'}_i x_{p'} z_{i'} = z_i x_{p'}
$$
so we have a structure like,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
z_2 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 x_1 \\ z_1 x_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
z_2 x_1 \\ z_2 x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This can be summarised as,
$$
(\pmb{I} \otimes \pmb{x}) \cdot \pmb{z}= \pmb{z}\otimes \pmb{x}
$$
The only issue is that unless you are very familiar with the notation
of matrix algebra (I am not) it is not straightforward to interpret how
$\cdot$ acts on a Kronecker product.

It is not true that $\delta^{i'}_i x_{p'}=x_{p'}\delta^{i'}_i$; although tensor elements have this property (since they are scalars)
it is not the case that $\delta^{i'}_i x_{p'}$ is the same object as $x_{p'}\delta^{i'}_i$. The Kronecker product $\pmb{a}\otimes\pmb{b}$
in index notation can be written as $a_i b_j$; given $i,j$, $a_ib_j=b_ja_i$. But tensor $T_{ji}=b_ja_i \neq a_ib_j=T_{ij}$ unless $T_{ij}$
is symmetric.